# SCCM client installation failing

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, sccm

We are currently attempting to installing the sccm to clients but we have found that the push method is very hit and miss.

Server:
Server 2008 R2 
SCCM 2007 R3

Clients:
Win7 x64

Issue with push:
Client is listed in SCCM collections
Reimage client using WDS
SCCM does not attempt to reinstall client. (Unless I delete the client from collections)

I've also tried deploying via GPO (msi) but as part of other GPO installs a reboot stops its process. This causes it to fail - even though its suppose to retry every 10 minutes.

Note. WSUS is not itegrated in SCCM.

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following your question. Sounds like you are imaging computers using WDS, not SCCM, with a client installed in the image already. After imaging a computer the client does something it shouldn't? Why would it need to be reinstalled?

Deployment via GPO with the MSI file is not recommended. You should have the computer or user run a "script" at boot/login to call the setup program. This will setup an installation service temporarily on the computer, insuring that if the computer is rebooted during installation that it will continue and eventually finish. Why would the GPO retry every 10 minutes?

Comment: Client is not install into the image. What I meant was when using WDS to reinstall the OS, after its done reinstalling (no client as part of WDS image) SCCM doesn't try to push its client out to the reinstalled machine.